# How to bind a ScrollHandler on the body in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, html, dom, gwt

I want to attach a ScrollHandler on the page body element. I know that I can do

```
RootPanel r = RootPanel.get();
```

to get the body element. But it does not has an addScrollHandler method.

**How do I add a scroll handler to the body?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the event on the `Window` object instead

```
Window.addWindowScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {         
            @Override
            public void onWindowScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                int scrollX = event.getScrollLeft();
                int scrollY = event.getScrollTop();

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the difference adding it to Window or RootPanel?

Comment: If the RootPanel takes 100% of the window width and height, it wouldn't make any difference. Also, Window is a browser related object, while RootPanel is an AbsolutePanel that contains all the application widgets. We could say that Window contains RootPanel.

Comment: So binding a ScrollEvent on Window will bind it to body in HTML?

Comment: No, because it's the RootPanel that contains the Body object. If you want to get the Body in GWT you do something like this Element body = RootPanel.getBodyElement();

Comment: What do you recommend for controlling the main scrollbar of a page? Bind a ScrollEvent onWindow or on the body?